# XmlNode.SelectSingleNode recursively to export CSV

Tags: xml, powershell, export-to-csv

I'm trying to export a csv with FileZillaServer data from XML config.
It works as exepcted, except for the condition `Where-Object` due to it stopped on the first block with the same name `<Permissions>`.
I'd like to get `Permission Dir` value only if it's set to HomeDirectory `"IsHome">1`

XMl contains:

```
<FileZillaServer>
    <Users>
        <User Name="USER1">
          <Option Name="Pass">e1923304e508b24dc0</Option>
          <Option Name="Salt"></Option>
          <Option Name="Group"></Option>
          <Option Name="Bypass server userlimit">1</Option>
          <Option Name="User Limit">0</Option>
          <Option Name="IP Limit">0</Option>
          <Option Name="Enabled">0</Option>
          <Option Name="Comments">Comment 1</Option>
          <Option Name="ForceSsl">0</Option>
          <IpFilter>
                <Disallowed />
                <Allowed />
          </IpFilter>
          <Permissions>
                <Permission Dir="C:\folder1\subfolder1">
                    <Option Name="FileRead">1</Option>
                    <Option Name="FileWrite">1</Option>
                    <Option Name="FileDelete">1</Option>
                    <Option Name="FileAppend">0</Option>
                    <Option Name="DirCreate">0</Option>
                    <Option Name="DirDelete">0</Option>
                    <Option Name="DirList">1</Option>
                    <Option Name="DirSubdirs">1</Option>
                    <Option Name="IsHome">0</Option>
                    <Option Name="AutoCreate">0</Option>
                </Permission>
                <Permission Dir="C:\folder1\subfolder2">
                    <Option Name="FileRead">1</Option>
                    <Option Name="FileWrite">0</Option>
                    <Option Name="FileDelete">0</Option>
                    <Option Name="FileAppend">0</Option>
                    <Option Name="DirCreate">0</Option>
                    <Option Name="DirDelete">0</Option>
                    <Option Name="DirList">1</Option>
                    <Option Name="DirSubdirs">1</Option>
                    <Option Name="IsHome">1</Option>
                    <Option Name="AutoCreate">0</Option>
                </Permission>
              </Permissions>
                    <SpeedLimits DlType="0" DlLimit="10" ServerDlLimitBypass="0" UlType="0" UlLimit="10" ServerUlLimitBypass="0">
                <Download />
                <Upload />
          </SpeedLimits>
        </User>
    </Users>
</FileZillaServer>
```

I'm using this code:

```
$xmlFilePath = "C:\FileZilla Server.xml"
$newcsv = "C:\newcsv.csv"
$xml = [xml](Get-Content $xmlFilePath)
 
$results = foreach ($user in $xml.FileZillaServer.Users.User){                                                
                [pscustomobject]@{
                User = $user.Name
                Comment = $Comments = $user.SelectSingleNode("Option[@Name='Comments']").InnerText = $user.SelectSingleNode("Option[@Name='Comments']").InnerText
                ForceSSl = $ForceSSL = $user.SelectSingleNode("Option[@Name='ForceSsl']").InnerText = $user.SelectSingleNode("Option[@Name='ForceSsl']").InnerTex
                Enabled = $Enabled = $user.SelectSingleNode("Option[@Name='Enabled']").InnerText = $user.SelectSingleNode("Option[@Name='Enabled']").InnerText                          
                HomeDir = $user.Permissions.SelectSingleNode("Permission[@Dir]").Dir | Where-Object {$user.Permissions.SelectSingleNode("Permission[@Dir]/Option[@Name='IsHome']").InnerText -eq 1} 
                                 }                                                          
} $results | export-csv $newcsv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: It might be a cut&paste error, but your xml isn't valid - it's missing a ```</Permissions>```, probably immediately before the ```<SpeedLimits DlType="0"...```.

Comment: Can you also show what the expected csv output should be from your  xml?

Comment: I think the first `SelectSingleNode()` always wants to pick the first choice since your conditional statement exists outside of its XPath. Maybe `HomeDir = ($user.Permissions.SelectNodes("Permission[@Dir]") | where {$_.SelectSingleNode("Option[@Name = 'IsHome']").Innertext -eq 1}).Dir` would have better results. Once you reference `.Dir`, node selection ends because that's an element of text. Therefore, that should happen last.

Comment: You can do it all in XPath if you want - ``FileZillaServer/Users/User/Permissions/Permission[descendant::Option[@Name='IsHome']='1']`` - i.e. get me all the ```Permission``` nodes where there's a child ```Option``` node with name ```IsHome``` and value ```1```. See http://xpather.com/vhV0c4Zy for a live demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
$xmlFilePath = "C:\FileZilla Server.xml"
$xml = [xml](Get-Content $xmlFilePath)
 
$results = foreach ($user in $xml.FileZillaServer.Users.User){                                                
               [pscustomobject]@{                        
                    HomeDir = $user.Permissions.SelectSingleNode("Permission[@Dir][./Option[@Name = 'IsHome'] = '1']").Dir
               } 
}
```

The XPath predicate `[./Option[@Name = 'IsHome'] = '1']` creates a condition where the current node (`Permission`) contains a child node `Option` with an attribute called `Name`. `Name` must have a value of `IsHome` and the text for that `Option` node must be `1`.

---

The reason the `HomeDir` property was not set as expected is because of how the selection conditions are ordered.

`$user.Permissions.SelectSingleNode("Permission[@Dir]").Dir` selects the first node that is named `Permission`, which contains an attribute named `Dir`. When that node is selected, the property `Dir` is referenced on that PowerShell object. Ultimately, you are returning the string that represents `Dir` ***and then piping that to `Where-Object`***. Any piped `Where-Object` conditions after that will only filter that string further.

If you wanted to rely on `Where-Object` to filter, you can do something like the following:

```
($user.Permissions.SelectNodes("Permission[@Dir]") | where {
    $_.SelectSingleNode("Option[@Name = 'IsHome']").Innertext -eq 1}).Dir
```

Notice how the `Dir` property value is retrieved ***after*** the node, attribute, and text conditions are applied. `SelectNodes()` is used because we need to send all potential nodes to `Where-Object` for it to filter further.